# UIButton changes shape when pressed

Tags: objective-c, animation, uibutton, image-size

```
-(IBAction)actionButtonPressed:(id)sender {
//Write the code to show the buttons etc like play
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent
                 animations:^{
                     [self.actionBtn0 setFrame:CGRectMake(25, 25, 100, 100)];
                     [self.actionBtn1 setFrame:CGRectMake(40, 40, 70, 70)];
                     [self.actionBtn2 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 150)];

                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                                           delay:0.0
                                         options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                                      animations:^{
                                          playBtn.alpha = 1.0;
                                      }
                                      completion:NULL];
                 }];

}
```

I have a button that when the app loads it is large and in the centre of the screen. However, when it is pressed i want it to shrink down in size and move to the top right of the screen. There are actually 3 buttons but they all share the same IBAction shown above.

The problem I am having is that depending on when the button is pressed the images of the buttons morph into random weird shapes that i did not specify. The images should be perfectly circular but they tend to be redrawn elliptically. Any idea how to stop this?

The original dimensions of the buttons before the button is pressed are below.

```
actionBtn0 = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 185, 200, 200)];
[actionBtn0 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bigLineRing.png"] 
forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[actionBtn0 addTarget:self action:@selector(actionButtonPressed:) 
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:actionBtn0];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:actionBtn0];

actionBtn1 = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(90, 215, 140, 140)];
[actionBtn1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"smallLineRing.png"] 
forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[actionBtn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(actionButtonPressed:) 
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:actionBtn1];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:actionBtn1];

actionBtn2 = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 135, 300, 300)];
[actionBtn2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"theEye.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[actionBtn2 addTarget:self action:@selector(actionButtonPressed:) 
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:actionBtn2];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:actionBtn2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using this creation of UIButton;

```
actionBtn1 = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(90, 215, 140, 140)];
[actionBtn1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"smallLineRing.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

try to use this:

```
actionBtn1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
actionBtn1.frame = CGRectMake(90, 215, 140, 140);
[actionBtn1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"smallLineRing.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: I had same problem before if you forget to change any of button type custom it occurs. If you use image in UIButton never use Round Rect Button as a type.